# C# Entity Framework 4.1: include paths in query for loading related objects

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

When I run this line of code

> queryCompanies = (DbSet)queryCompanies.Include(path);

from this method:

```
     public Company GetCompanyById(int companyId)
     {
        List<string> includePaths = new List<string>();
        includePaths.Add("Addresses");
        includePaths.Add("Users");
        Company company = null;
        using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
        {   
            var queryCompanies = dbContext.Companies;

            if (includePaths != null)
            {
                foreach (string path in includePaths)
                    queryCompanies = (DbSet<Company>)queryCompanies.Include(path);
            }

                company = (from c in queryCompanies
                           where c.Id.Equals(companyId)
                           select c).FirstOrDefault<Company>();
        }
        return company;
     }
```

I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ClassLibrary1.Company]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[ClassLibrary1.Company]'.

At compilation I have no error. In EF 4.0 this code runs correct using instead of DbSet<>, ObjectQuery<>.

I am a beginner in EF 4.1 so any suggestion will be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 public Company GetCompanyById(int companyId)
 {
    List<string> includePaths = new List<string>();
    includePaths.Add("Addresses");
    includePaths.Add("Users");
    Company company = null;
    using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
    {   
        var queryCompanies = dbContext.Companies.AsQueryable();

        if (includePaths != null)
        {
            foreach (string path in includePaths)
                queryCompanies = queryCompanies.Include(path);
        }

            company = (from c in queryCompanies
                       where c.Id.Equals(companyId)
                       select c).FirstOrDefault<Company>();
    }
    return company;
 }
```

Comment: cadrell0, thanks for the answer, it works fine with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=VS.103%29) inherits from [DbQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696530%28v=VS.103%29), so the compiler doesn't complain since the cast could be valid.  Apparently, what `DbSet<T>.Include` returns is not a `DbSet<T>` and the cast fails at runtime.

However, you do not need to cast; calling `FirstOrDefault` will work on `DbQuery<T>`.

Comment: The issue is that queryCompanies is of type DbSet<T>.  The for loop where he is adding the Includes cannot set the DbQuery<T> to DbSet<T>, so he added the cast.  Converting dbContext.Companies to a queryable (with AsQueryable) removes the need to cast the result of the Include.

Answer (score 0):

I write a generic include checker method. This is not good now but it is work. I will refactor this. Maybe it meets your needs.

```
    List<TEntityType> GetEntityListTemplate(Expression<Func<TEntityType, bool>> expression = null)
    {
        List<TEntityType> entityList;
        DbQuery<TEntityType> query = null;

        Type entityType = typeof(TEntityType);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entityType.GetProperties();

        using (DatabaseContext database = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            database.Database.Connection.Open();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("Your.Identifier.Namespace"))
                {
                    if (query == null)
                    {
                        query = database.Set<TEntityType>().Include(property.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = query.Include(property.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (query == null)
            {
                if (expression == null)
                {
                    entityList = database.Set<TEntityType>().ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    entityList = database.Set<TEntityType>().Where(expression).ToList();
                }
            }
            else //(query!=null)
            {
                if (expression == null)
                {
                    entityList = query.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    entityList = query.Where(expression).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        return entityList;
    }
```